# Change Elementor Loop Order On a Click

Tags: wordpress, elementor, easy-digital-downloads

I'm using the Elementor Loop widget to display Easy Digital Downloads products.

The loop orders the products by their title.

I want to add a dropdown box and let the visitors order the products by last modified date, most popular, price, etc.

I know how to add the dropdown box, but I have difficulty changing the loop order based on the selection.

How do I approach it?

Thank you